# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Class;

Tags: spring-boot, runtime-error, classnotfoundexception, classcastexception

I just tried to checkout a spring boot code and executed in my STS and gives this error. Even this is not giving any hint about the real issue. Like which class is not found and all. I cannot share the code due to copy right issue. Is there any way to get some detailed log ?

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Class;
>       at org.springframework.plugin.core.config.PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:45) ~[spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$$Lambda$141/429075478.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>       at com.stackroute.keepnote.UserAuthenticationServiceApplication.main(UserAuthenticationServiceApplication.java:51) [classes/:na]

Comment: it is very dificult to give you an answer without the code, that error seems to be internal, inside spring libs.

Comment: @DougllasSousa yea I understand that.  As you said this is not a problem of code I guess,    I deleted my maven repo and then again created it . No luck.

Comment: You could debug the code and add a breakpoint at PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:45 to see what happens

Comment: @SimonMartinelli thanks for the support. Actually it was an issue with  spring jar file versions. But the exception was misleading and a debug helped to solve it.